# My setValue is not working in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set the value to the value that has been entered by the user in a prompt when  the value in `e11` is different than "MC ou CC"

I am able to get the value from the prompt and display it in the `logger.log` but somehow the value is not transferred to the `D11` cell.

```
Function onEdit(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Demande");
  if(s.getRange("E11").getValue() != "MC ou CC"){     
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() ;
    var Bouton =   ui.prompt('Veuillez entrer le montant du paiement 
    mensuel', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var Reponse = Bouton.getResponseText();
    if (Bouton == ui.Button.OK) {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "OK" or the close button in the d 
      ialog\'s title  bar.'+Reponse);
      s.getRange("D11").setValue(Reponse);
    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the 
      dialog\'s title  bar.'+Reponse);
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

You need to get the [getSelectedButton()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getselectedbutton) in order to find out which button the user clicked.

### Solution based on your answer:

**Replace** `if(Bouton == ui.Button.OK)` **with** `if(Bouton.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK)`:

```
function myFunction() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Demande");
  if(s.getRange("E11").getValue() != "MC ou CC"){     
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() ;
    var Bouton =   ui.prompt('Veuillez entrer le montant du paiement mensuel', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var Reponse = Bouton.getResponseText();
    if (Bouton.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "OK" or the close button in the dialog\'s title  bar.'+Reponse);
      s.getRange("D11").setValue(Reponse);
    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title  bar.'+Reponse);
    }
  }
 }
```

since you execute this function manually, there is no need to use an `onEdit` trigger. Instead you can use a regular function and hence I changed the name. If you want to use the `onEdit` trigger properly, then see the recommended answer below.

### Recommended Solution:

- The `onEdit` trigger and generally trigger functions are
  not supposed to be ran manually as you do right now.
- The `onEdit` trigger is activated when the user changes the value of
  a cell.

Take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.range;
  if(s.getName() == "Demande" && rng.getA1Notation()=='E11' && rng.getValue()!="MC ou CC"){    
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var Bouton =   ui.prompt('Veuillez entrer le montant du paiement mensuel', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var Reponse = Bouton.getResponseText();
    if (Bouton.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "OK" or the close button in the dialog\'s title  bar.'+Reponse);
      s.getRange("D11").setValue(Reponse);
    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title  bar.'+Reponse);
    }
  }
 }
```

**Be careful:**

- This solution uses the **event object** and it is the recommended way to use an `onEdit` trigger. This won't work if you manually execute the function. It will only work when the user makes changes to the value of a cell.
- It assumes that you only want to execute the code inside the main `if` condition when you edit the value of cell `'E11'` in the sheet `"Demande"`. So it will only work when you edit the cell `'E11'` in `"Demande"`.

If you want a different behaviour, let me know and I will modify the code accordingly.